# Receiving Unicast and Multicast on the Same Socket in C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets, network-programming, multicast

I need to receive both unicast and multicast UDP on the same socket and port at a specific IP. Based on other questions asked here, this should be possible. I can set all the options and bind successfully, but I cannot receive any traffic. It just stays blocked at `read()` call.

I have tried many different options, such as `SO_BROADCAST`, `SO_REUSEADDR`, and `SO_REUSEPORT`. I have tried setting multicast group address to "0.0.0.0," but that fails. I just don't know how to properly do this.

Here is a stripped-down version of my current status:

```
struct sockaddr_in localSocket;

int sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
//error check here

int broadcast = 1;
//I have tried either one of these options, as well as SO_BROADCAST. 
// Now I am trying to use both
if ((setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&broadcast, sizeof(broadcast)) < 0 || 
    (setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, (char*)&broadcast, sizeof(broadcast)) < 0)) 
    //error handling here
else 
{
    memset((char*) &locakSocket, 0, sizeof(localSocket));
    localSocket.sin_family = AF_INET;
    //port that I want to receive on
    localSocket.sin_port = htons(port);
    //local IP that I want to receive on. I have tried "0.0.0.0" here as well, 
    //but I still do not receive anything
    localSocket.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP); 
}

if(bind(sd,(struc sockaddr*)&kicakSicjetm suzeif(localSocket))<0)
    //error handling
else
{
    //trying to join multicast here:
    struct ip_mreq group;
    //IP address that the multicast is being sent from. 
    // I have tried "0.0.0.0" here too, but that fails.
    group.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("239.255.1.1");
    //local IP that I want to receive on. 
    I have tried skipping this line, but I still do not receive any traffic
    group.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr(IP);
}

if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &group, sizeof(group)) < 0)
    //error handling
else
{
    while(!terminate)
    {
        //this breakpoint is hit, but I never hit any line afterwards
        numbytes = read(sd,packet,sizeof(packet));
    }
}
```

Since I get to the final line, I know that none of the `setsocketopt()`, `bind()`, etc fail. I just don't ever read anything.
Am I doing something out of order? It feels strange to `setsockopt`, `bind`, and then `setsockopt` again, but that is where my research lead me.

edit: This is for a linux system.
There were two issues:
`if ((setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&broadcast, sizeof(broadcast)) < 0 || (setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, (char*)&broadcast, sizeof(broadcast)) < 0))` 
and
`localSocket.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP);`

I simply commented out the pair of `setsockopt` such that I did not `setsockopt` until near the end. I was using incorrect socket options such as `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_REUSEPORT`. Additionally, I was binding to my local IP that I wanted to receive on instead of binding to `IPADDR_ANY`. Thanks to all for the help

Comment: You are binding your socket to a specific interface. Is the unicast peer sending packets directly to that interface IP? Is the interface connected to the same LAN subnet where the unicast/multicast peer are connected to? What do the multicast and unicast sending codes look like? Did you verify with a packet sniffer, like Wireshark, that the unicast/multicast packets are reaching the PC at all, and to the specific interface?

Comment: staying blocked at `read()` call, maybe means that it waits to receive data, when you broadcast some data by a client it will pass on that line.

Comment: "_IP address that the multicast is being sent from._" You do not send multicast from a multicast group. Multicast can only be a destination address, not a source address.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, the unicast peer is sending packets directly to that IP. Are they on the same subnet -- yes, I am successfully receiving unicast from that peer in another thread, socket, and port that is not related to this question. Multicast and unicast sending codes--not sure what you mean by this. Packet sniffer--there is definitely some unicast being sent, but I do not know if it is the unicast from the aforementioned separate thread or this thread. I do not know how to see multicast on wireshark; I will look into that now. To the specific interface--by that do you mean IP? if so, yes

Comment: @fa7eme agreed, I think that I am not receiving any data, or else I would proceed past that line

@RonMaupin alright, maybe I am confused. The sender is calling `udp_sendto` with a `dst_ip` of 239.255.1.1. Does that not mean that I need to listen to 239.255.1.1? From the receiver's perspective, doesn't it functionally mean that traffic is coming from that IP?

Comment: The multicast packets need to be sent to the multicast group IP.  The receiver needs to `bind()`+`recvfrom()` on a local interface that is joined to the multicast group. When the OS receives a packet, it checks if the packet is targetting a multicast group, and if so deliver it to all interfaces that are joined to that group. That part appears fine. The receiver will receive the sender's IP, not the group's IP, as the source address of each packet. Off-hand, I don't see any problem in the code shown, other than using `read()` instead of `recvfrom()`. This may be a networking issue instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You were right. I did not see multicast on Wireshark. I changed the sender code (which is in C) to send a blank `pbuf` of size 1 (is that still enough to trigger `read()`/`recvfrom()`? I don't know how to populate `pbuf`s, will look into later), and now `udp_sendto` is sending correctly, and I see some multicast on Wireshark. I changed my `read` line to `if(recvfrom(sd, packet, sizeof(packet), 0, NULL, NULL) <0)...` and I still don't exit that line. I have never used `recvfrom`, so I will now look into how to use it

Comment: I changed the sending `pbuf` to have 2 bytes of data (I think). I don't see any problems with `recvfrom`. Going to play around with more options now that I know I am actually sending something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Linux, when receiving both unicast and multicast traffic on the same socket you **must** bind to `INADDR_ANY`, i.e. 0.0.0.0.  If you bind to a specific interface you won't get multicast traffic, and if you bind to a multicast address you won't get unicast traffic.

So set up your bind address like this:

```
memset((char*) &locakSocket, 0, sizeof(localSocket));
localSocket.sin_family = AF_INET;
localSocket.sin_port = htons(port);
localSocket.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

You also *don't* want to use `SO_REUSEADDR` or `SO_REUSEPORT`.  When receiving multicast, it does allow you to have two open sockets on the same port which will both receive multicast traffic, however it's not well-defined whether unicast traffic goes to both, only to one, or round robin.  You also don't need `SO_BROADCAST` in your receiver as that only controls outgoing datagrams sent to a broadcast address (i.e. x.x.x.255).

The way you're joining the multicast group looks good.  Note that if you expect multicast traffic to come in on multiple interfaces then you'll need to join the group on each one.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you should use `recvfrom` to receive data from a UDP socket.  This allows you get the source IP/port of the incoming datagram and also allows you to set socket-specific flags if needed.

Comment: Yes, I am running on Linux.    
    
  
"must bind to `INADDR_ANY`"  
"don't want to use `SO_REUSEADDR` or `SO_REUSEPORT`" 
  
That was it, thank you. I had tried the former, but I always set a wrong `setsockopt` in the past.     
  
Thanks for the additional information in the last two paragraphs as well.   
  
I will edit the OP momentarily